# How to fix a Visualforce "Could not resolve the entity from value binding" error?

Tags: apex, visualforce

As a Beginner to Sales force following error is coming while I am making a page of commercial. Kindly help me out.

This is  following code of my commercial object in which there are 4 record type-buy, sell rent In and Rent out. having field dependencies   Pick list .

> Error: Could not resolve the entity from  value
>   binding '{!Property Type}'.  can only be used with
>   SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

```
<apex:page controller="Commercial"  >
 <apex:form >
 <apex:messages style="color:red"></apex:messages>
 <apex:pageblock title="Commercial">
 <apex:pageblockbuttons >
 <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>
 <apex:commandButton value="Save&New" action="{!Quicksave}"/>
 <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
 </apex:pageblockbuttons>
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="You are Looking for" columns="1" collapsible="false">
  <apex:pageblockSectionItem > 
  <apex:outputLabel value="I want to -" for="rt" /> 
  <apex:panelGrid columns="2"> 
  <apex:outputText value="RecordType" rendered="false" />
   <apex:selectList id="rt" value="{!RecordType}" size="1" required="true">
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="Select" itemLabel="Select"/>
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="Buy" itemLabel="Buy"/>
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="Rent In" itemLabel="Rent In"/>
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="Rent Out" itemLabel="Rent Out"/>
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="Sell" itemLabel="Sell"/>
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecordType}"/> 
   </apex:selectList>  
  </apex:panelGrid>
  </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
   <apex:pageBlockSection title="Choose the Property" collapsible="false" >
   <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
   **<apex:inputField value="{!Property Type}"/>**
    <apex:inputField value="{!Status}"/>
   </apex:pageblocksectionItem>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
   <apex:pageblockSection title="Choose the Property Sub Type" collapsible="false" >
   <apex:inputField value="{!Property Sub Type}"/> 
   <apex:inputField value="{!Construction Age}"/> 
   <apex:inputField value="{!Bathrooms}"/> 
   <apex:inputField value="{!Condition}"/> 
    </apex:pageblockSection>
   <apex:pageBlockSection title="Criteria  by Size and Price  " collapsible="false" >
   <apex:inputField value="{!Size Unit}"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!Price Unit}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
   <apex:pageblockSection title="Choose the Minimum and Maximum Size" collapsible="false" >
     <apex:inputField value="{!Size Min}"/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!Size Max}"/>
   </apex:pageblockSection>
   <apex:pageblockSection title="Expected Budget" collapsible="false"  >
   <apex:inputField value="{!Budget (Min)}"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!Budget Max}"/>
   </apex:pageblockSection>
   <apex:pageblockSection title="Amenities" collapsible="false"  >
   <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
   <apex:inputField value="{!Amenities}"/>
   </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
   </apex:pageblockSection>
   <apex:pageblockSection >
   <apex:inputField value="{!Brokerage Type}"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!Brokerage Comission}"/>
   </apex:pageblockSection>
  </apex:pageblockSection>
 </apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: is "Property Type" a field in Object Commercial?

Comment: no its a pick list . Brokerage commission is  number field   and rest all are pick list which are dependent to each other. like property type and property sub type have field dependencies and so on.. .

Comment: The value attribute uses the API name of a field (not its label), and typically a custom controller would provide a reference to the SObject to the page. So `value="{!c.Property_Type__c}"` with `c` a reference to a `Commercial__c object` is what is normally in Visualforce. I suggest you read some introductory material such as [An Introduction to Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce).

Comment: @Keith C - Thank you so much for the valuable info..

Comment: Keith, can you post that as an answer? I'd say you're right on the money, the spaces do give the game away!

Answer (score 2):

The value attribute uses the API name of a field (not its label), and typically a custom controller would provide a reference to the SObject to the page. So:

```
value="{!c.Property_Type__c}"
```

with `c` a reference to a `Commercial__c` object is what is normally in Visualforce.

I also suggest you read some introductory material on Visualforce such as [An Introduction to Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce) before going much further.

Comment: now its saying -Error: Unknown property 'String.RecordType'

Comment: @sfdcDeveloper I suggest you Google and otherwise research yourself on this problem for a while. That is a good way to learn. There are also resources like the [Visualforce Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_vf/workbook_vf.pdf) which will give you a good grounding on how to do things in Visualforce. If you are still stuck after that, post a new question with both the page and controller as one question/one answer is the format of this site. (I don't know the cause of this problem.)